# ASP.NET Razor : error when generating scaffolded item

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm following the Microsoft tutorial about getting started with Razor. You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). I'm facing an issue at [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). When generating the scaffolded item, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-the-movie-model-2), I'm receiving the following error :

```
Minimal hosting scenario!
Generating a new DbContext class 'wf-decision.Data.wf-decisionContext'
Attempting to compile the application in memory with the added DbContext.
There was an error creating a DbContext :C:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(5,9): error CS1002: ; attendu
(8,23): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions
(8,13): error CS1514: { attendue
(9,1): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue
(10,20): error CS1514: { attendue
(10,20): error CS1513: } attendue
(10,20): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue
(10,21): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions
(10,37): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue
(10,39): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions
(11,5): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue
(12,16): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions
(12,18): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue
(12,55): error CS1003: Erreur de syntaxe, ',' attendu
(12,56): error CS1003: Erreur de syntaxe, ',' attendu
(19,1): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue
(12,19): error CS1520: La m├®thode doit avoir un type de retour
(17,48): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions
(12,36): error CS0308: Impossible d'utiliser le type 'DbContextOptions' non g├®n├®rique avec des arguments de type
(12,56): error CS0246: Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'decisionContext' est introuvable (vous manque-t-il une directive using ou une r├®f├®rence d'assembly┬á?)
(13,15): error CS1729: 'object' ne contient pas de constructeur qui accepte des arguments 1
C:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(17,31): error CS0118: 'wf' est un espace de noms mais est utilis├® comme un variable
C:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(17,34): error CS0103: Le nom 'decisionContext' n'existe pas dans le contexte actuel
C:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(17,1): error CS0201: Seuls une assignation, un appel, un incr├®ment, un d├®cr├®ment et des expressions d'objet await et new peuvent ├¬tre utilis├®s comme instruction
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:06.28
Scaffolding 'RazorPageEntityFrameworkCRUD' has finished with errors:
 * Scaffold item command has finished with error: There was an error creating a DbContext :C:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(5,9): error CS1002: ; attendu(8,23): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions(8,13): error CS1514: { attendue(9,1): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue(10,20): error CS1514: { attendue(10,20): error CS1513: } attendue(10,20): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue(10,21): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions(10,37): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue(10,39): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions(11,5): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue(12,16): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions(12,18): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue(12,55): error CS1003: Erreur de syntaxe, ',' attendu(12,56): error CS1003: Erreur de syntaxe, ',' attendu(19,1): error CS1022: D├®finition de type ou d'espace de noms, ou fin de fichier attendue(12,19): error CS1520: La m├®thode doit avoir un type de retour(17,48): error CS0116: Un espace de noms ne peut pas contenir directement des membres tels que des champs, des m├®thodes ou des instructions(12,36): error CS0308: Impossible d'utiliser le type 'DbContextOptions' non g├®n├®rique avec des arguments de type(12,56): error CS0246: Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'decisionContext' est introuvable (vous manque-t-il une directive using ou une r├®f├®rence d'assembly┬á?)(13,15): error CS1729: 'object' ne contient pas de constructeur qui accepte des arguments 1C:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(17,31): error CS0118: 'wf' est un espace de noms mais est utilis├® comme un variableC:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(17,34): error CS0103: Le nom 'decisionContext' n'existe pas dans le contexte actuelC:\Users\tanquetil\Dev\OFPRA\wf-decision\wf-decision\Program.cs(17,1): error CS0201: Seuls une assignation, un appel, un incr├®ment, un d├®cr├®ment et des expressions d'objet await et new peuvent ├¬tre utilis├®s comme instruction
```

Useful information :

- I'm using JetBrain's Rider, version 2022.3.2
- SDK .NET version : 6.0.407

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1601) (github.com) where someone has apparently the same problem on Visual Studio, but it seems there is no solution provided.

I'm currently installing Visual Studio to see if the problem persists. I would appreciate if anyone has a clue about this.

Comment: include your code for "program.cs"...  it seems to be complaining about a missing semi-colon.

Comment: Does your project have any compile errors? From your error message, it seems to less `,` in your code,

Comment: I'll put the content of `Program.cs` as soon as I can, but the thing is I have no compile error at all. The exact same process gives me no error on Visual Studio. It only happens using Rider, with the exact same code.